# How can I debug an issue causing queries to get stuck waiting on ClientRead indefinitely?

Tags: postgresql

Today an issue suddenly appeared in our database clients where ~0.01% of queries would get stuck indefinitely - Postgres says it's waiting on the client to read and the client also says it's waiting to read, resulting in nothing happening. This is in a configuration that has worked without issue for many months.

Our client configuration at the time was to have no query timeout, which was causing the connection pool to quickly become exhausted from these "lost" queries. After adding a query timeout of 30 seconds, we can observe about 1 query time out every ~5 seconds. The client located on the same machine as the database is the only one not experiencing this issue, which clearly points to some kind of network problem. None of the clients are sitting at 100% cpu usage and neither is Postgres.

Running this query:

```sql
SELECT client_addr, pid, age(clock_timestamp(), query_start), wait_event_type, wait_event
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE query != '<IDLE>' AND query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%' 
ORDER BY query_start;
```

Produces this output:
[image]
Where the top three queries are "hung" and will time out and all the others are OK and will complete.

My question is, what can I do to diagnose this problem? I have tried restarting each of the machines involved, allocating Postgres more resources, and running `mtr` to try and detect packet loss between the client and server. There's 0% packet loss over many thousands of samples and nothing else has fixed the problem, so I'm still at a complete loss as to what is failing and why.

Comment: I've never seen or heard of this problem before, but that state does not mean it is waiting for the client to read, it means it is waiting to read from the client.  That is, it is waiting for the client to write something (like the next statement it intends to run).

Comment: If it's a network issue, then perhaps this is the wrong site for the question.  Run a ping log from the client to the server.